# My form only adds one user, I can add another one when i delete the previous user in my database. Anyone has any tips?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, user-registration

I know my code looks bad, but I just started using PHP. I can't fix the problem and I have been looking online for hours.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, pass) VALUES ('$username', '$pass')"; 
    $sql_check = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    $res_check = $conn->query($sql_check);


    if ($res_check->num_rows > 0) {
        $melding = "Gebruikersnaam is al in gebruik";  
    } else if($res) {
        $melding =  "Gebruiker geregistreerd";
    } else {
        $melding =  "Gebruiker niet geregistreerd";
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors from database? Do you have unique index on some column?

Comment: nope, I have not seen any errors.

Comment: You are not _checking_ for any errors. You won’t get any by default, unless you have configured your database connection to throw exceptions in case of an error, or your explicitly _ask_ the database, if there was an error. (Both been explained numerous times already, so please do a bit of research, if this doesn’t ring any bells with you yet.)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Have you got error reporting enabled? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: I already have few things to help against SQL injection. I will hash passwords when it works properly. I was doing research to PDO but I didn't understand it, I would like to use Mysqli instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check if your table already has an unique AND auto incrementing index!

Explanation:
If you add an entry the database will give it an unique id (counting from 1).
But if the field is not set as "auto incrementing" the index will always be zero and therefore it will fail to add another entry.

In phpmyadmin:
go to "structure" and edit the field ID. Check "AI" (auto increment) and make sure that it is used as primary key (key symbol).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
$conn
```

is mysql connection variable

```
$username
```

user name variable

```
$pass
```

is user password

```
user_signup($conn,$username,$pass);
// Call function 
function user_signup($conn,$user_name,$password)
{
$sql_check = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$user_name'";
$res_check = $conn->query($sql_check);
if ($res_check->num_rows > 0) {
echo "Username already exists!";
} else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, pass) VALUES ('$user_name', '$password')"; 
$conn->query($sql);
echo "insert data successfully"; 
// you can redirect another page
}
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I still can add only one user. I want to add more than one. But still thanks for your time.

Comment: You want add multiple user data give me reply

Comment: Yes, I can only add a second user when i delete the user i created before. So what I am trying to say is that I can only have one user at the time

Comment: You want like sign up  if one user are already sign up than give message like username already exists. Give me reply

Comment: Yes, it has to show me if username already exists.

Comment: I edit answer check out is sign up function and SQL connection ,user name , password